# how to start a headless virtualbox machine from jenkins job

Tags: virtualbox, scheduled-tasks, jenkins, runas

I have  Windows 7 pro SP1 with a Jenkins installation running with SYSTEM account. I also have VirtualBox and a virtual machine created in my personal user with Debian, to be used as a slave for Jenkins for compilation stuff. So, I'm trying to start the vm using a specific job in jenkins, using `VBoxManage.exe startvm DebianJenkins --type headless`. But, given that this command is executed with SYSTEM account, the vm doesn't exist (VMs are specific to users). The commands runs perfectly running with my personal user.

So, I'm trying to run the command with my personal account, using runas /savecred or using a scheduled task and calling the task with `schtasks /run /TN "DebianJenkins agent"`. But, with the runas, I need to perform the command at least once from cmd with SYSTEM privileges to insert the password (then, because of /savecred, the password is stored and jenkins can execute the command without inserting password); I don't know how to do it. The scheduled task is also failing and can't get an error message, code or so to guess the reason.

What I really want to do, is to create a job that automatically starts the VM, compile some programs in the VM and stops the VM after getting the generated artifacts. So, any help with all that would be welcome, cause I don't have any more ideas to get it working.

Thank you.